# Preposições em inglês no histórico de revisões

Tags: bug, localização, internacionalização, histórico-de-revisões

Sobraram umas preposições sem tradução nas mensagens de fechamento e reabertura que aparecem no histórico de revisões das perguntas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/2509/revisions</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/3076/revisions</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/32499/revisions</sup>

Não sei se é problema de localização ou internacionalização, então estou colocando as duas tags.

Comment: Descobrir se isso é um problema que **eu** posso resolver, ou se tenho que passar pros devs (basicamente a diferença entra `localização` e `internacionalização`) é bem difícil mas **parece** ser algo que vai ter que ser passado pra eles. Vai ter que esperar um pouco.